# Can the Firebase config file that must be placed in /android/app/ be read by people who might tinker with my application's build?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

Let's say I have a React Native Android application which uses React Native Firebase. As per React Native Firebase, I have to download the firebase config file and place it `/android/app/` in order for React Native Firebase to initialize the default firebase application. This config file contains the API key and I was wondering if the API key is actually secure this way.

Obviously I'd imagine it is secure, since placing the file in the aforementioned folder is a React Native Firebase requirement.

Comment: The values in that file are **configuration** data, not any form of secret. See my answer to the question I linked for more on this (in the context of a web app, but the same appleis to all platforms).